# Using a systemd service to create a file

Tags: systemd

I am trying to create a systemd service to clear a directory of old files automatically. If l were to do this manually, l would be using a pair of commands like

```
$ /usr/bin/touch -t $(/usr/bin/date -d'-7day' +%Y%m%d%H%M) /tmp/cutoff
$ /usr/bin/find /path/to/dir ! -newer /tmp/cutoff -exec rm {} \;
```

The former line does in fact generate the placeholder file in the `/tmp` directory. However, the following service definition

```
[Unit]
Description=Cleanup index cache left behind by bup backup
Type=oneshot

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/touch -t $(/usr/bin/date -d'-7day' +%%Y%%m%%d%%H%%M) /tmp/cutoff
SyslogIdentifier=%p
```

Fails to generate the place-holder

```
$ /usr/bin/touch -t $(/usr/bin/date -d'-7day' +%Y%m%d%H%M) /tmp/cutoff
$ ls -l /tmp/cutoff
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Mar 20 14:36 /tmp/cutoff
$ rm /tmp/cutoff
$ sudo systemctl start cleanup_index_cache
$ ls -l /tmp/cutoff
ls: cannot access '/tmp/cutoff': No such file or directory
$ 
$ sudo systemctl start cleanup.service
$ ls -l /tmp/cutoff
```

If there is a way to delete files/directories older than a certain age using systemd? Is there something l'm missing in just transcribing shell commands to systemd directives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

systemd does not send commands in `ExecStart=` and its relatives through the shell. It executes them directly. So you cannot use shell constructs such as `$()`.

It's not clear why you're generating a date and touching a file with it anyway. `find` is perfectly capable of finding files older than a certain time on its own.

From the man page:

```
       -mtime n
              File's  data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments
              for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
              of file modification times.
```

That bit explains:

```
       -atime n
              File  was  last  accessed n*24 hours ago.  When find figures out
              how many 24-hour periods ago the file  was  last  accessed,  any
              fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to
              have been accessed at least two days ago.
```

`find` is also capable of deleting files on its own and does not need to call out to `rm` (and it's potentially a bad idea to do so for a variety of reasons).

```
       -delete
              Delete files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed,
              an  error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's exit sta‐
              tus will be nonzero (when it eventually exits).  Use of  -delete
              automatically turns on the `-depth' option.

              Warnings:  Don't  forget that the find command line is evaluated
              as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to
              delete everything below the starting points you specified.  When
              testing a find command line that you later intend  to  use  with
              -delete,  you should explicitly specify -depth in order to avoid
              later surprises.  Because -delete  implies  -depth,  you  cannot
              usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```

So to delete files older than 7 days, you can simply run `find` directly, with no other funny stuff:

```
/usr/bin/find /directory -mtime +6 -delete
```

Answer (score 4):

`systemd-tmpfiles` is a systemd's feature that can be configured to clean old files from a directory automatically. Instead of a new service that requires startup every time a directory cleanup is needed, one could create a file under `/etc/tmpfiles.d/` with the following content:

```
# /etc/tmpfiles.d/cleanup_index_cache.conf
d /path/to/dir - - - 7d
```

References: [tmpfiles.d (5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html) ; [systemd-tmpfiles (8)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html)